# Training ML algorithm in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am new to Pyspark, trying to create a ML model in Pyspark
My goal is to create a TFidf vectorizer and pass those features to my SVM model.
I tried this

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("Stream")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
parallelized = sc.parallelize(Dataset.CleanText)
             #dataset is a pandas dataframe with CleanText as one of the column
from pyspark.mllib.feature import HashingTF, IDF
hashingTF = HashingTF()
tf = hashingTF.transform(parallelized)

# While applying HashingTF only needs a single pass to the data, applying IDF needs two passes:
# First to compute the IDF vector and second to scale the term frequencies by IDF.
#tf.cache()
idf = IDF().fit(tf)
tfidf = idf.transform(tf)

print ("vecs: ",tfidf.glom().collect())
         #This is printing all the TFidf vectors


import numpy as np
labels = np.array(Dataset['LabelNo'])
```

Now how should I pass these Tfidf and label values to my model?

I followed this
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html

and tried to create labeled point as

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkSessionZipsExample").getOrCreate()

dd = [(labels[i], Vectors.dense(tfidf[i])) for i in range(len(labels))]
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(dd),schema=["label", "features"])

print ("df: ",df.glom().collect())
```

But this is giving me error as:

> ---〉 15 dd = [(labels[i], Vectors.dense(tfidf[i])) for i in range(len(labels))]
>        16 df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(dd),schema=["label", "features"])
>        17
>
> TypeError: 'RDD' object does not support indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly explains itself `RDD does not support indexing`. You are trying to get the `ith` row of `tfidf` by using `i` as its index(`tfidf[i]` in line 15). RDDs don't work like lists. RDDs are distributed datasets. Rows are randomly distributed to workers.

You have to collect the `tfidf` to a single node if you want your code to work but that would defeat the purpose of a distributed framework like spark.

I would advise you to work with dataframes instead of rdds as they are much faster than rdds and `ml` lib supports most of the operations(HashingTF, IDF) provided by `mllib`.